# Getting Value Error when assigning row based on multiple condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When running the line

```
conditions = [
    (df['a']>=4 & df['a']<=7),
    (df['a']>=8 & df['a']<=15)
]
```

The compiler return

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

May I know why this happen?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame([1,3,6,2,4,10,4,5,15],columns=['a'])

conditions = [
    (df['a']>=4 & df['a']<=7),
    (df['a']>=8 & df['a']<=15)
]
#
choices = [1,2]
#
df['points'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

Comment: You lack the parentheses, use `((df['a']>=4) & (df['a']<=7))`.

Comment: This Question has already been answered on the below link in Staack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o The or and and python statements require truth-values. For pandas these are considered ambiguous so you should use "bitwise" | (or) or & (and) operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your condition by adding `()`

```
conditions = [
         (df['a']>=4) & (df['a']<=7),
         (df['a']>=8) & (df['a']<=15)
              ]

df['points'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
df
Out[329]: 
    a  points
0   1       0
1   3       0
2   6       1
3   2       0
4   4       1
5  10       2
6   4       1
7   5       1
8  15       2
```

Or with `ge` and `le`

```
conditions = [
    df['a'].ge(4) & df['a'].le(7),
    df['a'].ge(8) & df['a'].le(15)
]
```

And between

```
conditions = [
    df['a'].between(4,7),
    df['a'].between(8,15)
]
```

Comment: Hi Beny, while at it, can you also add in your suggestion the `between`. I just found about this amazing function. `conditions = [
    (df['a'].between(4, 7)),
    (df['a'].between(8, 15))]` . Cheers

Comment: @rpb added :-) `